# Vibrate command only works when Settings > Sounds > Vibrate switch is on

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak

I'm using the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) to vibrate the phone but it only works when Settings > Sounds > Vibrate switch is on. How can I vibrate my phone when Settings > Sounds > Vibrate switch is off programmability. My phone is jailbroken.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The vibrate option switch needs to be turned on.

You will need to edit **com.apple.springboard.plist**

```
NSString *sbPath = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.springboard.plist";

NSMutableDictionary *sbDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:sbPath];

[sbDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"ring-vibrate"];
[sbDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"silent-vibrate"];
[sbDict writeToFile:sbPath atomically:YES];

/* Check to make sure the settings took */
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

You can also send a notification to update the preferences. I'm not sure if this still works though.

```
notify_post("com.apple.SpringBoard/Prefs");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to do it programmability.

Comment: You can edit the Springboard prefs file. **com.qpple.springboard.plist**

Comment: Thanks！I do that before. It just change the UI show, and cannot vibrate the phone when AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) call. I think this plist describe the UI, not  the function.

Comment: Either way, the hardware switch must be in the ON position. If its OFF, nothing will happen.